# Explicitly Load Library (DLL) into Legacy function pointers

Tags: windows, dll, dynamic-linking

I will try to be as specific as possible.

I need to explicitly load a PythonXX.dll at run-time into my routine.  I am using the nominal descriptions (Python.h) to describe the functions.  The problem is that the linker complains that these routines are not present.  I cannot change the function definitions to make the linker happy, because there are scattered about the Python #include code structure.

My thinking at this point is to create stub routines that call a function pointer to be loaded when the .dll is loaded at run-time.  The stubs make the linker happy, and they operate correctly when the .dll is loaded during run-time. 
 But this has some problems too. [Some functions are #defines of other routines, varags are difficult to redirect, etc.]

Is there a better way to do this?  I can't believe this hasn't occurred before.  If anything is unclear, I will edit and clean up the question to clarify.

Update:  OK, this seems to work, at least with some of the routines. (Fortunately, I only need to use about 20 of the 1000+ functions of the .dll)

An example function pointer definition:

```
int (__cdecl *pPy_IsInitialized)(void);
```

An example stub:

```
int Py_IsInitialized()
{
  return pPy_IsInitialized();
}
```

An example assignment  (dll is return from LoadLibrary() ):

```
pPy_IsInitialized = (void *)GetProcAddress(dll,"Py_IsInitialized");
```

Comment: paste exactly function declaration, which lib file you use (how this api named here) which error (full exactly message) return linker to you

Comment: @RbMm The question is generic and it not really related to specific DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use [delay-loaded DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx). This feature delays load of DLL (`PythonXX.dll` in your case) until any of it's functions is called. You can customize the actual library load (e.g. load it from specific location) via [delayed-load helper function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds.aspx).

As a side note, the solution which you proposed in your question makes perfect sense and is easily automatable. Delay-loaded DLLS implements it for Windows and my [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) does the same for Linux shared libraries.

Comment: The delay-loaded DLLs seem interesting.  Not sure it is the best fit for me.  And there are apparently techniques for passing variable arguments to another function.  We will see.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Jiminion Note that it's basically an automated way to insert stubs which you mention in your question.

Answer (score -1):

I might ask why you want to do this, but I will try to answer your question:

Generally you link the lib for the DLL you want to use to your image (dll, exe, etc.).  The Windows loader will *automatically* load your depndencies before you get loaded.  The OS' loader also has support for delay loading an image which is a good idea to conserve resources and speed up your code.

If you don't like the loader autmoatically doing things, you may call [LoadLibary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) directly with an image's (dll's) file path manually.  That gets the dll loaded into your process.  Then you can call [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) using the module handle which gives you a function pointer.  This is assuming that the DLL correctly exports the function you need.  Then you can cast the function pointer with the a function definition.  You can use that like you normally use a function, passing parameters, etc. in your code.  Static casting a function pointer shouldn't cause linker errors.

Taking a step back, API versioning is a common problem.  One way Windows has solved this in the past was with COM which allows you to version functionality through COM objects.  You may define N versions of an interface.  One dll and even one C++ object can implement them all or the can separated.  When you call something like CoCreateInstance, COM base splunks object registrations in the registry to load the correct DLL and instantiates the right version of the com object.

Windows also has a lot of C APIs.  Windows uses [API sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-apisets) to version the Win32 flat C-style APIs.  You may link a specific version of the API set to your program, but generally you would link an umbrella lib like onecoreuap.lib.  I know how to do this for a system component, but I am not sure if a 3rd party component can hook into this OS feature.

Generally this abstraction is something that the component would implement.  It is sort of weird for the component's client to do it.